# How to sort table by name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm still a beginner in ReactJS and I'm doing a job where I need to sort my list of pokemons by name.

I'm using the `Material-UI Table`, but I can't do the ordering. Here's is my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-water-o3snc?file=/src/App.js)

I know there are duplicate values in my list, but this is a problem that I will solve after I fix the order ^^

[image]

```js
import React from "react";

import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { pokemons } from "./data";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
    if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
    return order === "desc"
      ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
      : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
  }

  function stableSort(array, comparator) {
    const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
    stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
      const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
      if (order !== 0) {
        return order;
      }
      return a[1] - b[1];
    });
    return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
  }

  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <Table sx={{ maxWidth: 650 }}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Pokémon</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
            <TableRow
              key={pokemon.name}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row" thumbnailImage>
                <div className="thumb">
                  <img src={pokemon.thumbnailImage} alt="" />
                </div>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row" description>
                {pokemon.name}
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I assume you copy from [this](https://mui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting) example and miss some code there, but you can also use `DataGrid`, which has the [sort feature](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/sorting/) implemented already so you only have to set `sortable` to true when declaring the column.

Comment: Isn't [the documentation](https://mui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting) on this pretty clear? You need to create to create a header component that you use instead of TableHead. Take a look at the example code of `EnhancedTableHead` and how it's used in `EnhancedTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i just made some improvements in your code. You can check it out now.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { pokemons } from "./data";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [pokemonsState, setPokemonsState] = useState(pokemons);
  const [isAsecSort, setIsAsecSort] = useState(false);

  const onClickName = () => {
    if (isAsecSort)
      setPokemonsState(stableSort(pokemons, getComparator("aesc", "name")));
    else setPokemonsState(stableSort(pokemons, getComparator("desc", "name")));

    setIsAsecSort(!isAsecSort);
  };

  function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
    if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
    return order === "desc"
      ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
      : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
  }

  function stableSort(array, comparator) {
    const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
    stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
      const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
      if (order !== 0) {
        return order;
      }
      return a[1] - b[1];
    });
    return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
  }

  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <Table sx={{ maxWidth: 650 }}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Pokémon</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" onClick={() => onClickName()}>
              Name
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {pokemonsState.map((pokemon, idx) => (
            <TableRow
              key={idx}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                <div className="thumb">
                  <img src={pokemon.thumbnailImage} alt="" />
                </div>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row">
                {pokemon.name}
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Things I changed -:

1. Used the sorting function with 'name' as comprable.
2. In pockemon mapping on DOM I used index as key because name was repeating.
3. You used some weird fields (like thumbnailImage) in JSX element. So I removed them.
   Now it is completely error free.

Edit 1 -: To sort the array only after clicking name I added onClickListener on Name element (to make some hover effect you can use css or button/anchor tag). For automatic rerendering I used useState hook for storing pokemons instead of normal array.

Edit 2 -: To toggle the sort on each click I added a isAsecSort counter which will sort in ascending order if true else will sort in descending order.

Comment: Could you explain what the OP did wrong?

Comment: I mentioned in last. Sorting function did not called to sort the pokemon. And some others errors like using name as key in map function where name was repeating and using unknown JSX property like thumbnailImage.

Comment: "Sorting function did not called to sort the pokemon" - this was the correct answer.  It should be the first answer in your post, before all of your other help.

Comment: Hey Sahil, thank you for your help, but I would like to sort my list, when the user clicks on the "Name" column, could you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: @Tainara I just edited the code. Please check.

Comment: Hey Sahil, that works, but it does the filter only once, when I click more than once, to do the reverse order, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Look my updated code: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-water-o3snc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Tainara what do you mean by reverse ?

Comment: Does it mean to change the sorting order or again the random one ?

Comment: Hi Sahil, it means ascending and descending order, now it's working just descending order

Comment: @Tainara I just edited code again. Please check and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Hey Sahil, that's worked perfectly for me, thank you very much!!!!